# Allow User's Music to Play when Application is Running - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm not completely sure if this is used with Cocos2d, but I would like to know how I could let the user play their own music from their playlists or if my application could randomly choose a song from their playlist.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: I just removed any background music I had and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if another music is playing using CDAudioManager singleton. Use the function `isOtherAudioPlaying`. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_d_audio_manager.html#ab664b34e99f6f3e2158f2df910cf3a95